# Bash Script to get Value of Key from file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that contain list of users and his token value like :

```
- name: A@X/xxxxxx:123
  user:
    token: abcdefghijk
- name: B@Y/yyyyyyy:456
  user:
    token: dassafsdfscczcz
```

I want to get token value for specific name using bash script ?

Comment: Is this a YAML file? Don't parse it with non-syntax aware tools.

Comment: i edited the post , i need to get token value for specific name

Comment: Install a proper YAML parser - https://github.com/0k/shyaml

Comment: Is there is bash Script  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep:

```
grep -A 2 "A@X/xxxxxx:123" THEDATAFILE | grep token | cut -d':' -f2
```

It will work even if you have the same user twice and print both tokens.

Tested with GNU grep on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ param="A@X"
$ awk '{if($2~/name/) {a=$3} else {print a,$0}}' temp |grep token|grep $param|awk '{print $3}'
abcdefghijk
```